# How to make exception when I get message of "if could not find the specified object"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm initializing userform with optionbutton that matching with variable.
OptionButton need to be turned on if variable is matching.
OptionButton can not be continuous and having error with "Could not find the specified object".

This is excel VBA, I was trying to make exception, but didn't work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Integer, obj As Object, Fruit As String, Meat As String
Fruit = "BANANA": Meat = "BEEF"
For i = 11 To 23
    Set obj = Controls("OptionButton" & i)
    If obj Is Nothing Then

    Else
        If obj.Caption = Fruit Then obj.Value = True
        If obj.Caption = Meat Then obj.Value = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

please give me a comment how to make exception for this error.

Comment: if I change to obj As MSForms.Control, it's still give a same error.

Comment: @urdearboy: Like what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the form elements, and operate only on those which are of type `OptionButton`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim FormElement As Control            ' Enumerates the form elements
  Dim OptnBtn As OptionButton           ' Enumerates OptionButtons

  Dim Fruit As String, Meat As String   ' Criteria for setting the buttons

  Fruit = "BANANA"
  Meat = "BEEF"

  For Each FormElement In Me.Controls
    On Error Resume Next
      Set OptnBtn = FormElement
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not OptnBtn Is Nothing Then
      If OptnBtn.Caption = Fruit Or OptnBtn.Caption = Meat Then
        OptnBtn.Value = True
      End If
      Set OptnBtn = Nothing
    End If
  Next FormElement

End Sub
```

The `for each` / `next` statement iterates over the form elements, setting `FormElement` to each of the form elements in turn. For each such element, we try to set `OptnBtn` to that element; for elements which are not option buttons, this will fail and leave `OptnBtn` set to `Nothing`.

Note that you cannot have more than one `OptionButton` True selected in one group. If you want to have to have two or more option buttons selected in a form they must be in different groups.